# How Ternary Operator Works with null check

Tags: java

```
ccnCustomizedLabelData.setCCN_TRANSPORTATION_MODE(null != shipRequestVo.getTransportationMode() ? shipRequestVo.getTransportationMode() : null);
```

We have a null check before the getter method.
Need to understand the behavior of the ternary operator with the null check.

Comment: remove redundant code and you'll see it more clearly

Answer (score 2):

```
null != shipRequestVo.getTransportationMode() ? shipRequestVo.getTransportationMode() : null
```

if null != shipRequestVo.getTransportationMode() is not equal to null then the value is what ever is being returned by shipRequestVo.getTransportationMode()

or else null is returned

Comment: "then the value is what ever is being returned by nul != shipRequestVo.getTransportationMode()". No. That should be: "then the value is whatever is being returned by shipRequestVo.getTransportationMode()"

Comment: basically: it always returns the value of shipRequestVo.getTransportationMode(), the condition here is not needed